# How do I add a class node to a generic linked list?

Tags: c#

I'm making a generic linked list and I have to make two sets of data.

First file is "auto.txt" which contains information about cars in the following format:

```
Brand Model Year
```

Second file is "moto.txt" which contains information about motorcycles in the following format:

```
Brand Model Year Engine
```

I made a two-way linked list and I need to make two lists, one containing the motorcycles and other containing cars. However, I get the following errors:

```
cannot convert from 'L3_Console.Car' to 'T'
cannot convert from 'L3_Console.Motorcycle' to 'T'
```

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenList<Car> Cars = Read<Car>("auto.txt");
        GenList<Motorcycle> Motorcycles = Read<Motorcycle>("moto.txt");
    }

    public static GenList<T> Read<T>(string Failas)
    {
        GenList<T> List = new GenList<T>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(Failas, FileMode.Open), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(Car)) List.Add(new Car(parts[0],parts[1],int.Parse(parts[2]))); //error here
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Motorcycle)) List.Add(new Motorcycle(parts[0], parts[1], int.Parse(parts[2]),parts[3])); //error here
            }
        }
        return List;
    }
}

public sealed class GenList<T>
{
    private sealed class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

        public Node() { }

        public Node(T data, Node<T> adr_p, Node<T> adr_n)
        {
            Data = data;
            Previous = adr_p;
            Next = adr_n;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> start;
    private Node<T> end;
    private Node<T> current;


    public GenList()
    {
        this.start = null;
        this.end = null;
        this.current = null;
    }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        var dd = new Node<T>(data, null, start);
        if (start != null)
            start.Previous = dd;
        else end = dd;
        start = dd;
    }

}
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }

    public Car(string brand, string model, int year)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
    }
}
public class Motorcycle
{
    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }
    public string Engine { get; private set; }

    public Motorcycle(string brand, string model, int year,string engine)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
        Engine = engine;
    }
}
```

How do I properly add a new node to the list, containing a class which depends on how the function was called? Thank you

Comment: Lots of questions on the site already asking about this. See e.g. marked duplicate. Short version: when you try to add to the list the compiler has no way to know that `T` is `Car` or `Motorcycle`. `T` could be anything at that point, as far as the compiler can tell (no, it's not going to look at your `if` statement). You need to cast it to be explicit. For what it's worth, the code would be better if you passed a `Func<string[], T>` to the method and let the caller decide how to convert a `string[]` to a suitable `T` that could be added to the list. Then no type-checking or casting is needed.

Comment: E.g. in your loop, have only a single statement like: `List.Add(factory(line.Split(' ')));`, where the method declaration is changed to: `GenList<T> Read<T>(string Failas, Func<string[], T> factory)`, and where you call like this, for example: `Read<Car>("auto.txt", parts => new Car(parts[0],parts[1],int.Parse(parts[2])));`

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you, you are a genius!